# I need to escape double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In the example below I run str through .replace and populate the div with id of wtf with the output. The problem is I have to manually escape the double quotes for str.replace to work.
Is there a way to automatically escape the double quotes?

```
<body>
    <div id="wtf"></div>
<script>
var str = ("this string has "double quotes" as well as 'single quotes'..");

var well = str.replace(/\s\d{2}\s(\d{2}\s)?/g,' ');

wtf.innerHTML = well;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: str is invalid then further ahead how javascript interpreter would go???? use a slash to escape the quote...

Comment: Shouldn't `"this string has "double quotes" as well as 'single quotes'.."` be `"this string has \"double quotes\" as well as 'single quotes'.."`?

Comment: Nope, there is no way since the JavaScript cannot be executed since it is a syntax error.

Comment: When I see your `str`, I have the same expression as your `div` id

Comment: Why would you deliberately code in the wrong syntax, and then try to escape it with more code? Huh?

Comment: what I'm actually doing is copying code examples from books I read using kindle for windows. When I paste the code into my text editor it also copies line numbers and inserts spaces. The code has both single and double quotes so I can't use .replace I tried to use addslashes but I'm not deep into php and don't know if it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape the double quotes manually. There's no way to do automatically because the str produce the following error then javascript wouldn't execute further ahead lines of code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the backslash ( **\** ) to escape your double quotes.

It should look like this :

```
var str = ("this string has \"double quotes\" as well as 'single quotes'..");
```

There's no automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the quotes, it is best to replace them with their HTML entity. Using a method like this, you can accomplish it.

```
var tokens = [
        ['"', '&quot;'],
        ["'", '&#039;']
];
var clean = [];

for(var i = 0; i < MY_STRING.length; i++) {     
  var s = MY_STRING[i];
  for(var a = 0; a < tokens.length; a++)
    if(tokens[a][0] == s) {
      s = tokens[a][1];
      break;
    }
    clean.push(s);                      
}
var cleanString = clean.join("");
```